# How to identify if a view is scrollable view in Android?

Tags: android, view, android-custom-view

I am creating a custom view. I need to parse parents till i get the scrollable view. **How can I identify that the view is Scrollable view ?**

One simple way to do this is :

```
while(view != null){
        if(view.getParent() instanceof View) {
            view = (View) view.getParent();
        }
        else{
            view = null;
        }

        if(view instanceof ListView){
            scrollableParentView = view;
            break;
        }
        else if(view instanceof ScrollView){
            scrollableParentView = view;
            break;
        }
        else if(view instanceof GridView){
            scrollableParentView = view;
            break;
        }
        else if(view instanceof HorizontalScrollView){
            scrollableParentView = view;
            break;
        }
    }`
```

With this approach my implementation will fail if tomorrow we get new scrollable view by android.

Please suggest some good approach.

One more question : **How can I listen the parent scrollView event in my custom child view?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you want to find scrollable parent???

Comment: I want to listen Scrollevent of parent (Scrollable view) and do some animation on my custom view.

Comment: use ViewTreeObserver#addOnScrollChangedListener

Comment: @pskink I Tried using scrollableViewParent.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(onScrollChangedListener);     But ChangedListner is fired if any other view (Not the parentView) is also scrolling.

Comment: @pskink  when i do scrollableViewParent.getViewTreeObserver() ,  Will it return the view tree from root or from the calling view ?

Comment: just call getViewTreeObserver on your custom view, not parent,  why parent?

Comment: I tried the same. But when i am scrolling any other view in the activity this scroll event is called.

Comment: Even so,  what's the problem with that?

Comment: Its unnecessary processing when some other view is scrolling.

Comment: so use your original way...

Answer (score 1):

To detect a **scrollable** view you can check if it's scrollable to some specific direction:

```
if (view.canScrollHorizontally(1)) {
    // Scrollable to right
} else if (view.canScrollHorizontally(-1)) {
    // Scrollable to left
} else if (view.canScrollVertically(1)) {
    // Scrollable to top
} else if (view.canScrollVertically(-1)) {
    // Scrollable to bottom
} else {
    // Un-scrollable
}
```

Comment: How can I listen the parent scrollView event in my custom child view?

Answer (score 0):

you could try doing a try catch implementation, I think it'll throw a ClassCastException ..

```
try{
//scrollview initialization
}catch(ClassCastException e){
//error message?
}
```

Comment: What will i do in NullPointerException ?

Comment: sorry my bad, I think you should throw ClassCastException.. here's the thing, if a ScrollView is not detected on the current layout it will throw an exception.